# Creating Minimum Value with Random Operator in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, random

I need to generate a random number that is between a minimum value and 1 -> [min, 1)

I have been reading over the random class of java, and have found that when generating a random double, the result is a double from 0 to 1.0, however, you cannot limit the bound.

My original thought was to limit the top value of the random function to .7, but this is not possible with the random function.

If anyone could help me here's my code:

```
public static double random(){
        // generate an random number accuracy within range [min, 1)
        Random randomNum = new Random();
        double accuracy = min + randomNum.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Min " + min);
        return accuracy;
    }
```

If for example we take min to be .2 in this case, then the possible results of the function as I understand are .2 to 1.2. How can I make it simply .2 to 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't this work:

```
public static double random(int min, int max){
    Random randomNum = new Random();
    return (max - min) * randomNum.nextDouble() + min;
}
```

Explanation:

- `(max - min)` returns the difference between `max` and `min`.
- `randomNum.nextDouble()` returns a random number between `0` and `1`
- `+ min` will add the `min` value so it's the lowest value
- `(max - min) * randomNum.nextDouble()` returns a random number between `0` and `max-min`
- `(max - min) * randomNum.nextDouble() + min` returns a random number between `min` and `max`

Answer (score 2):

```
 /**
  * A double uniformly distributed in the range [min, max).
  * @param min finite and inclusive.
  * @param max finite, > min, and exclusive.
  * @return d such that min <= d && d < max.
  */
 public static boolean uniformInRange(double min, double max, Random r) {
   assert min < max && !Double.isInfinite(min) && !Double.isInfinite(max);
   return min + (r.nextDouble() * (max - min));
 }
```

To use it, just call

```
 uniformInRange(min, 1.0d, randomNum)
```

Comment: The earlier name was clearer imho, `uniformInRange` doesn't say anything about it being random. (ps: how many edits are you going to make, I've counted 10 already :P)

Comment: @WoLpH, I think the `Random` in signature makes it clear that this is a random number, and the word "uniform" is otherwise missing unless you delve into the Javadoc.  On edits, yeah, I'm really bad at looking at my code and then noticing just one more thing to tweak :)

Comment: @WoLpH It's doesn't really not say anything, "uniform" should be a good indicator to anyone who took statistics, especially in the context of random numbers. (Indicated by the containing package / class name for instance. Or the question being answered.)

Comment: @millimoose: you are right that "uniform" is quite clear in this context, but when I'm simply looking for a `random` function in my autocomplete list I would start by typing `random<tab>` ;)

Comment: @WoLpH, I think we're debating API design while missing a chunk of the picture : the class in which it appears.  If you were working inside the `Random` class or a subclass, then no methods would show up for the prefix "random", but the class name would provide the missing context.  If I were to build a complete library I would try to have a searchable class name while trying to avoid words like "random" which can lead to incorrect assumptions about "pseudo-random" vs "true-random".

Comment: @MikeSamuel: that is true, I didn't think about that. We'd need a little bit more information before we can say something useful about that.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
double min = .2;
Random gen = new Random();
double rand = (gen.nextDouble() * 0.8) + min;
```

Here you are adding the min bound at the end, and multiplying your 0-1 ratio by 0.8, which is the difference between 0.2 and 1.